# Passing value as reference

Tags: c++, reference

I have a function (method)

My struct is created by some complex objects, but in the end it acts like

```
struct MyStruct{

string a, b, c, d, e, f;
int g;
string h, k, l, n, o, p, q;
int r;
}
```

I did this way because its a database library and it uses inside those types, its more like a DBString, DBInt.

```
void CheckData(MyStruct& st){

}
```

In 32 bits when i try to access any value it works.
But in 64 bits after the fourth element my pointers "inside the object in the struct" points to nothing

Comment: I think there is no way to help, you need to provide more info about your problem.

Comment: Please show the definition of MyStruct.

Comment: What's `Void`? I mean, with the capital `V`

Comment: Its void in this case, sorry, my mistake

Comment: post the code you use to allocate the struct and call the `CheckData` function and the code that you use to access the elements (Where you have the problem)

Comment: From your description the problem is likely in the code that initializes the struct.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the problem was that the reference was sent to a external library and the define for my type was different in the external library.